# Override the output of views with angular directives

Tags: views, theming, 8

I use [Angular material](https://material.angularjs.org) in my Drupal 8 site (perforce!!!) and I have some problem with views.
 I want to override the output of views with custom text:

[image]

but as we all know views is strict with html tags and angular material uses custom directives for his purposes...

Question:

How to solve this problem?

How to make views to don't trim angular material directives?

Dose any one has solution for this?

UPDATE: The problem is that nothing is rendered correctly...

For example.

angular material card is this:

[image]

but the view shows this result:

[image]

This means that angular directives ware trimmed by Drupal, and that's why view shows incorrect result.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What gets trimmed by views?

Comment: You couldn't' do this with a "global" text field in Drupal 7, because it wasn't formatted text and the tags were stripped unconditionally. Looks like it's the same in Drupal 8. You'll probably have to write a custom Views extension to get that markup in there. I'd be tempted to write a simple formatted text field, copying most of it the code from the core one

Comment: thanks @Clive i see what u mean but can u pleas provide more information about your idea, or examples or is there any module for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and debugging i came across to this solution...

The problem of restriction of custom text field of a view is that it uses Xss::filterAdmin function (core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/PluginBase.php:398 line)...

So i created module, then in mymodule.views.inc file I alter "hook_views_plugins_field_alter", i changed class that uses the views custom text filed in my own class that i created in mymodule>src>plugin>views>field>my_Custom.php.
 This class is copy/paste of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/Custom.php and changed only the \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\PluginBase::viewsTokenReplace only this form:

```
$build = [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => $text,
    '#context' => $twig_tokens,
    '#post_render' => [
      function ($children, $elements) {
        return Xss::filterAdmin($children);
      }
    ],
  ];
```

to:

```
 $build = [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => $text,
    '#context' => $twig_tokens,
    '#post_render' => [
      function ($children, $elements) {
        return $children;
      }
    ],
  ];
```

and from now the custom text don't escapes html tags...

For more control i created also one checkbox in field setting to control f i want to escape the text or note for this field and accordingly to the value of checkbox i activate or deactivate the Xss::filterAdmin function